# Explanation of Bajo la Rosa

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, bajo-la-rosa

Recently I have watched Spanish thriller *Bajo la Rosa*. To tell the truth I do not understand the final twist.

The kidnapper after releasing the young girl (the daughter of the protagonists) told that the father will have to say something to his wife.

> From his confession results that the father raped his own daughter. I thought that it was the daughter of the kidnapper who was abused.

Who was finally raped in the movie?

Comment: You know you can hide the spoiler in a spoiler tag (`>!`), right?

Answer (score 1):

The father was a pederast. He was constantly molesting his own daughter at night. Furthermore, He drugged and sexually assaulted Lucía (his daughter's friend) when the girl stayed the night at Sara's house.
At the end of the movie, the mother says the father: "to your own daughter".

[Filmaffinity](https://www.filmaffinity.com/es/reviews/1/181566.html)

> Al final el padre confiesa que abuso de la amiga de su hija...Y por
>   extensión también abuso de su hija. Al final el hombre le da una
>   pistola para que decida que hacer con su marido.

[Filmaffinity](https://www.filmaffinity.com/es/reviews/2/181566.html)

> ...un padre odontólogo español (no argentino) y pederasta, ataca a su
>   hija y a una amiguita del cole después de narcotizarlas y el padre de
>   esta se coge la justicia por su mano. Para eso secuestra a la hija,
>   envía un mensaje en el que se autoinvita por la noche a la casa
>   familiar con el pretexto de hablar amenazando que en lugar de eso va
>   matar a la pequeña (¿?) y una vez ahí se dedica a torturar a la
>   familia toda entera...

[Sensacine](http://www.sensacine.com/miembro-Z20180328201331893473484/movie/245160/)

> ATENCIÓN SPOILER***Al final la mujer dice "a tu propia hija", si es
>   así como se explica el resto de la película...